# Which tomato variety is this?

Tags: tomatoes

I have made quite a comprehensive research about the topic but I still cannot determine the variety of the tomato that I grew and which is dead by now. But I have started a new one from its seeds so in order to determine its necessities, first of all one needs to determine the plant's variety. It is definitely a cherry tomato variety and since there are lots of cherry tomato varieties it is impossible for me to know. I have a list of cherry tomatoes if it will help:
[Cherry Tomato Varieties](http://www.thompson-morgan.com/tomato-selector-guide#cherrytomato)

[image: My plant]

I forgot to say that I bought this from IKEA as a plant, not as a seed and there was no variety name on the label. I am not even sure that this is a hybrid or heirloom. I hope it is the latter...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it would be impossible for any of us to say for sure what the variety is without finding out from IKEA directly, but it does look a bit like a Patio Princess Hybrid. It is a very small tomato plant bred specifically to do well and produce in a container. The size of the plant and of the tomatoes looks about right.

Comment: I agree that any answer from someone besides the grower would just be guessing, especially if the parent was a hybrid. It looks sort of similar to Husky Cherry Red, to me (in which case the parent was a hybrid).

Answer (score 3):

One of the most popular dwarf cherry tomatoes that would be the most likely candidates is Micro Tom.  Considering you got it from Ikea it would have to be a widely available tomato seed which Micro Tom is.  More info: http://t.tatianastomatobase.com/wiki/Micro_Tom